# Unable to Serve React App after Installing AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I cannot get my React app running on an EC2 Instance after deploying with CodeDeploy.

I have 3 Amazon Linux EC2 Instances running: **Production**, **Staging 1**, and **Staging 2**.

The Staging servers are imaged from Prod and all are running the same code. Our stack is a Node backend with React on the front.

**Staging 1**'s deploys are managed by CodePipeline/CodeDeploy. The Node server runs and I can query the back-end API, but it isn't serving our React app. Trying to access the front-end URL via browser/CURL will time out. **Staging 2** and **Production** work without issue.

Traffic is forwarded to the port the React app is running on via `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"` in the client's package.json.

I'm wondering what configuration the CodeDeploy agent could have changed to disable access to ports and proxying between React and Node.

Any demystifiation of what the CodeDeploy agent actually changes on an EC2 instance, or other potential cause would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: The following are the same across all instances :
**nginx config**,  **proxy settings in package.json**,   **ACL** (all instances are on the same VPC/Subnet),  **Security Groups** (all on same SG).

Comment: _"Traffic is forwarded to the port the React app is running on"_... how exactly is the React app _running_? Typically you just build the app which creates the HTML, JS, CSS, etc files and then serve them via a static HTTP server. Nginx is a popular choice

Comment: Are you saying you're running the webpack dev server in EC2? That's not what you want to do anywhere except for local development. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/